# Redirect variable page to variable subdomain wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am stuck on the follow htaccess situation.

I want to redirect pages to subdomains.

Url example right now;

http://domain.tld/user/foo

I need to redirect this to;

http://foo.domain.tld

The subdomain is genereated by wildcard.

I tried the follow without succes;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.tld?$
RewriteRule (.*) s/index.php?user=%1 [NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^user/(.*) (.*) [R=301,L]
```

Regards,

Nick

Comment: Have you set up a sub-domain for each user?

Comment: Its dynamic through a wildcard ('*.domain.tld') so just one sub domain who's catching all possibles.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.tld?$
RewriteRule (.*) s/index.php?user=%1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+) http://$1.domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hmmm, didn't do the trick, but also not a internal server error.